# Download/upload to laravel CSV

Tags: php, laravel, csv, mime

## Setup

- Laravel 9.x
- Ubuntu Server

## Background

I've created an inventory system for my client to manage/update their costs. Several of them wanted a mass upload/download system using CSV as it's how they preferred to work. Using a basic CSV export and import script I created this. However there is an obscure bug I would like to resolve.

I noticed it when I did an export followed by an immediate import. The laravel validation refused this, claiming it was not a CSV. Of course this has been importing successfully into Excel, so I investigated.

The MIME type of the exported file is not `text/csv` when exported from laravel.

## Question

How do I correctly export data as a CSV so that it saves correctly without a third party program "fixing it for me".

Edit: fie creation is as follows:

```php
        // create a csv
        $path = storage_path('app/uploads');
        $filename = 'parts.csv';
        $file = fopen($path . '/' . $filename, "w");

        // ...
        // a loop of adding $content using: fwrite($file, $content);

        fclose($file);
```

The current export is as follows:

```php
    // $path, $filename etc already set up

        return Response::download(
            $path . '/' . $filename,
            $filename,
            [
                'Content-Type: text/csv',
                'Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=' . $filename
            ]
        );
```

This creates a file that if immediately exported, has a basic text MIME type which gets rejected by a CSV validation.

Thanks all.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. There's too much info lacking from your question, missing code, missing usage instructions, missing error messages. Please also read [ask] for reference.

Comment: What is lacking Ulrich? There's no missing code: the relevant lines are included - anymore would not improve the quality of the question. 

Your complaint is also lacking detail... Linking to example question guidelines without specifics doesn't help either. It feels like you could be reviewing for reputation.

Comment: The given link explains what a [mcve] looks like. In particular the "verifiable" part is not fulfilled. Yes, that may be a significant amount of work in some cases, it ensures the quality of the questions though.